# How to understand the disjointness of a stabilizer code?

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

I'm reading [The disjointness of stabilizer codes and limitations on fault-tolerant logical gates](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.07256) and trying to understand the disjointness of a stabilizer code.

Does anyone have any intuition about or experience with the concept of disjointness of a stabilizer code?

For example, what is the disjointness of the Shor $ [[9,1,3]] $ code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I quickly threw together some code to play with this.

Define the Shor code and logical operator representatives

```python
shorgen = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,   1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,   0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,   0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,   0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
], dtype=int)

n = 9
m = 8

# logical operators
logX = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
logZ = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

We are interested in the support of operators. The support here is a list of length $n$ which has 1s where ever the operator has a non-trivial Pauli. Otherwise 0.

```python
# compute support of an operator
# an operator is a binary array of length 2n
def support(op, n):
    sup = np.zeros(n, dtype=int)
    for i in range(n):
        if op[i] == 0 and op[n+i] == 0:
            continue
        else:
            sup[i] = 1
    return tuple(sup)
```

Next, just determine all possible supports. For this we need to determine the support for every possible representative of $\bar{X}$. To do this, for every number from 1-2^m-1, we convert to binary string of length $n=9$. Then use the binary string to pick a subset of generators. Next multiply this subset of generators to get an element of $S$. Next multiply with `logX` ( or `logZ`) to get a logical operator representative.

We use a set to only save the unique supports.

```python
supX = set()
for i in range(1, 2**m):
    d = np.binary_repr(i,m)
    sel = np.array(list(d), dtype=int).astype(bool)
    op = (np.sum(cd.generator_matrix[sel,:],axis=0) + logX) % 2
    supX.add(support(op, n))

## supX has elements of the form
## (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
```

We can check that the minimum support sum is 3 for both `logX` and `logZ`, using the following line

```python
min([np.sum(g) for g in supX])
```

Hence, using the definition
[image: distance]

we can say that $d_\downarrow = 3$.

Finally, I quickly run a dumb optimization.

```python
c = 1
DeltacG = 0
for L in range(1, 6):
    for subset in combinations(supX, L):
        # count the support at each location. Then determine max
        # if max is greater than c, then discard. Else keep
        if max(np.sum(subset, axis=0)) <= c:
            A = subset
            DeltacG = len(A)/c
            
print(DeltacG)
print(A)
```

Running it for both `logX` and `logZ`, we determine that $\Delta_1(\bar{X}) = \Delta_1(\bar{Z}) = 3$.

Our goal is to determine

[image: delta]

The following lemma from the paper

[image: lemma]

shows that 3 is the max value of $\Delta$. And it seems like we have saturated it already for $c=1$. No need to calculate higher values of $\Delta_c$, though they seem to also all be equal to 3.

##### Important

I choose the simplest choice of the partition in the definition of $\Delta$, i.e. each qubit is in its own partition.

Comment: Great answer! So the disjointness is $ \Delta=3 $. The paper says  "if we choose a single-qudit partition, then those two quantities coincide, $d_\downarrow =d$." So indeed $d_\downarrow = 3=d$ as you say ($ XXX III III $ implementing logical $ Z $ witnesses this). Finally I think $d_\uparrow =3 $ since logical $ X $ is implemented by $ ZII ZII ZII $. So we have $ d_\uparrow =3 < 3 (3)= d_\downarrow (\Delta) $.

Comment: After doing the calculations, I think Shor code is not a good example to work with. Because both logical operators have a rep that is all $X$ or all $Z$. Which means the support is mostly determined by the elements of $S$ and the support of the operators plays less of a role in determining the disjointedness. You should repeat the calculations for codes which don't have this structure.